# I need help looping through this array of IDs that are not separated but is just a large element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to loop through this array of IDs. I know i could use a for loop or a forEach but the issue is, the commas do not separate these elements. They're just another element. Example:

```
var arr = [0123, 4567, 8901, 2345]
```

If I do an `arr.length`, I will get `20` instead of the `4` i'm expecting.I didn't create the code this is data i'm receiving from a database that i need to implement in a project.

Comment: you probably are recieving a string. Try arr = JSON.parse(arr). If doesn't work lease do console.log(arr) and post the result.

Comment: arr.length = 4 see https://ideone.com/8tC5MY

Comment: Junji Jazdanov That worked! much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's all in a string. Use regular expression to extract all numbers.

```
var str = '[0123, 4567, 8901, 2345]';
var regexp = /\d+/gi;
var matches_array = str.match(regexp);

alert(matches_array);
```